# problems using angular JSONP request

Tags: angularjs, cross-domain, jsonp

When i try using an  API on my angular js app get this error "Cross-Origin Request Blocked:" so i try using JSONP on the API

```
var req = {
method: 'POST',
url: 'http://192.168.43.25:8080/api/device',
headers: {
 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
 'X-Authorization': 'Bearer token',
 },
  data:  {'name': 'software'},
 }

 function deviceregister(){
  $http.jsonp(req).
    then(function(response) {
        $scope.formsuccess = response.data;
    },function(err) {
       $scope.formError = err;
      // called asynchronously if an error occurs
      // or server returns response with an error status.
    });
 }
```

here is the error i get when using the above code "Error: [$http:badreq]"

can anybody help me fix this?

Comment: does api even support jsonp? Not all do and not all support CORS and when neither is supported you need to use a proxy , either on your server or third party service

Comment: If you control the API server(and I guess you do, your URL is a private IP) you could just configure it to send `Access-Control-Allowed-Origin : *` headers. But that's not the recommended option, you should redesign your application so you don't have to make a cross origin request in the first place.

Comment: @charlietfl 
How do i use a proxy or which third party service is recommended? Any links is appreciated.

Comment: is that your api? If so enable cors. As for proxy, not hard to research

Comment: I am using a java servlet using spring configurations

Comment: so enable cors...also not hard to research how